# How to get the real cube root of a negative number in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python 3.4 seemingly randomly decides whether it returns the real or complex root of a number using the `**` operator:

```
>>> (863.719-2500)
-1636.281  
>>> -1636.281**(1/3)  
-11.783816270504108
>>> (863.719-2500)**(1/3)  
(5.891908135252055+10.205084243784958j)
```

Is there a way to ensure you get the real root when cube rooting rather than one of the complex ones?

Comment: In your first example, the order of operations means that you are taking the cube root of positive 1636.281 and then taking the negative of the result.

Comment: It's not random, but the consequence of defining `z**p` as `exp(p*log(z))` where the complex logarithm has a branch cut that puts its imaginary part in the interval (-π, π].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the second case actually the cube root is getting evaluated first then the minus sign is getting applied, hence the real root.

That is `-1636.281**(1/3)` becomes `-(1636.281**(1/3))` . And you can use a similar logic to get the real cubic roots as well.

But actually, when doing cubic root of negative numbers you always get complex numbers in python.

```
>>> -1636.281**(1/3)  
-11.783816270504108
>>> (-1636.281)**(1/3)
(5.891908135252055+10.205084243784958j)
```

If you want real numbers you can add code like -

```
def cube(x):
    if x >= 0:
        return x**(1/3)
    elif x < 0:
        return -(abs(x)**(1/3))
```

Comment: Oh, that would explain the weird behaviour. Also that code can be improved since 0**(1/3) is 0 you can just do if x >= 0: ... else: ...

Comment: I didn't understand the comment about `0` , its already returning `0` for `0`

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#the-power-operator

> In an unparenthesized sequence of power and unary operators, the operators are evaluated from right to left (this does not constrain the evaluation order for the operands): `-1**2` results in `-1`.

So your expression

```
-1636.281**(1/3)
```

is actually evaluated as

```
-(1636.281**(1/3))
```