# Cube root of negative numbers in a numpy array returns nan

Tags: python, numpy

From Numpy documentation:

```
>>> a = np.arange(10)**3
>>> a
array([  0,   1,   8,  27,  64, 125, 216, 343, 512, 729])
>>> a[2]
8
>>> a[2:5]
array([ 8, 27, 64])
>>> a[:6:2] = -1000    # equivalent to a[0:6:2] = -1000; from start to position 6, exclusive, set every 2nd element to -1000
>>> a
array([-1000,     1, -1000,    27, -1000,   125,   216,   343,   512,   729])
>>> a[ : :-1]                                 # reversed a
array([  729,   512,   343,   216,   125, -1000,    27, -1000,     1, -1000])
>>> for i in a:
...     print(i**(1/3.))
...
nan
1.0
nan
3.0
nan
5.0
6.0
7.0
8.0
9.0
```

Could somebody explain me the last line of code? How does `i to the power of 1/3` equal these numbers?

For example `-1000^1/3 = nan`? What part have I skipped over?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the real cube root of a negative number in Python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30923838/how-to-get-the-real-cube-root-of-a-negative-number-in-python3)

Comment: This question is not a duplicate. Even if you replaced the print statement as print((i)**(1/3.)) you would get the same behaviour

Comment: That won't work @AniketNavlur brother. I tried. It shows the same output

Comment: If possible and agreed then plz mark the answer verified. Happy to help you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, `(-1000)**(1/3.)` returns a complex number,

```
>>> (-1000)**(1/3.)
(5+8.660254037844384j)
```

This happens because the way computer store numbers, `1/3 = 0.33333...` is an irrational number which at some point gets approximated and therefore there is a loss in precision

---

```
>>> a = np.arange(10)**3
>>> a[:6:2] = -1000
>>> a
array([-1000,     1, -1000,    27, -1000,   125,   216,   343,   512,
         729], dtype=int32)
>>> for i in a:
     print((i)**(1/3.))


nan
1.0
nan
3.0
nan
4.999999999999999
5.999999999999999
6.999999999999999
7.999999999999999
8.999999999999998
```

Here the values in the ndarray `a` are of `numpy.int32` type.
The code `(i)**(1/3.)` returns a result of type `numpy.float64` since the second argument is a floating point.

```
>>> [type((i)**(1/3.)) for i in a]
[<class 'numpy.float64'>, <class 'numpy.float64'>, <class 'numpy.float64'>, <class 'numpy.float64'>, <class 'numpy.float64'>, <class 'numpy.float64'>, <class 'numpy.float64'>, <class 'numpy.float64'>, <class 'numpy.float64'>, <class 'numpy.float64'>]
```

`(-1000)**(1/3.)` is a complex number and cannot be stored as as `numpy.float64` therefore `nan`

---

To avoid the `nan` you can change the `dtype` of the `ndarray` to `numpy.complex` and do the calculations

```
>>> b = a.astype(np.complex)
>>> b
array([-1000.+0.j,     1.+0.j, -1000.+0.j,    27.+0.j, -1000.+0.j,
         125.+0.j,   216.+0.j,   343.+0.j,   512.+0.j,   729.+0.j])

>>> for i in b:
     print((i)**(1/3.))


(4.999999999999999+8.660254037844384j)
(1+0j)
(4.999999999999999+8.660254037844384j)
(3+0j)
(4.999999999999999+8.660254037844384j)
(4.999999999999999+0j)
(5.999999999999999+0j)
(6.999999999999999+0j)
(7.999999999999999+0j)
(8.999999999999998+0j)
```

You can take the absolute values of these numbers using `abs()`

```
>>> for i in b:
     print(round(abs((i)**(1/3.))))


10.0
1.0
10.0
3.0
10.0
5.0
6.0
7.0
8.0
9.0
```

Answer (score 5):

There is inbuilt function in numpy to find cuberoot.
Check this out:

```
print(np.cbrt(a))
```

Your output will be :

```
[-10.   1. -10.   3. -10.   5.   6.   7.   8.   9.]
```

Answer (score 0):

> How does `i to the power of 1/3` equal these numbers?

This is not just a NumPy or Python-specific feature. It's from math. *(In your example, it's numpy handling the math instead of Python, by overriding [`__pow__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.__pow__) but it works with pure-Python numbers as well.)*

```
>>> 2 ** 5  # 2 raised to 5
32
>>> 32 ** (1/5)  # 5th root of 32
2.0
```

x ** y (or "x raised to y"), 'y' can be:

- x ** 2 : *"x squared"*
- x ** 3 : *"x cubed"*
- x ** 5 : *"x raised to 5" or "5th power of x"*

It can also be a fraction:

- x ** (1/2) : *"square root of x"*
- x ** (1/3) : *"cube root of x"*
- x ** (1/5) : *"5th root of x"*

Here's a [source which explains it better](https://web.archive.org/web/20200401061203/http://lasp.colorado.edu:80/%7Ebagenal/MATH/math62.html):

> the Sqrt process actually undoes what the raising to the power of 2 had done; in other words, in some sense this is the "opposite" process of squaring. Recall from our algebraic rules for powers that a number to a power can be raised to a power again and all we do is multiply the powers; then note that the square root process can be written as raising to the power of ½:
>
> Sqrt(2²) = (2²)½ = 2² × ½ = 2^1 = 2

And for a more mathematical proof: [Why Is an Exponent of 1/2 the Same as a Square Root?](https://web.archive.org/web/20171227155147/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/65402.html)