# Calculate only real roots from fractional power in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, complex-numbers

I have a numpy array with negative and positive values, and I'm trying to raise it to the power of 1/3. I get `Nan` for all the negative numbers (which I understand because it involves complex roots), however, I want to print out the real roots instead of `Nan`.

Is there a fast pythonic way to do this? Beacuse for the third root, I know there will always be a real root.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-5,5,10)
z = x**(1/3)
```

And the result for `z` is:

```
array([       nan,        nan,        nan,        nan,        nan,
       0.82207069, 1.1856311 , 1.40572111, 1.57256466, 1.70997595])
```

I want `z` to contain all the real roots of the operation without `nan`.

Comment: I think this may answer the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52925585/cube-root-of-negative-numbers-in-a-numpy-array-returns-nan

Comment: What do you mean by the real root of a negative number?  The real component of the complex value, or the magnitude of that value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use trick like this:

```
z = np.where(x<0, -np.abs(x)**(1/3), x**(1/3))
```

Comment: this still calculates `x**(1/3)` on full `x` thus giving a `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power`. To avoid this, you can define a function

```
def my_pow(a, p): mask_neg = a < 0; mask_pos = a >= 0; a[mask_neg] = -(-a[mask_neg])**p; a[mask_pos] = a[mask_pos]**p; return a; 
```

my_pow(x, 1/3)

Answer (score 3):

You need [`cbrt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cbrt.html) function from `numpy`:

```
>>> np.cbrt(x)
array([-1.70997595, -1.57256466, -1.40572111, -1.1856311 , -0.82207069,
        0.82207069,  1.1856311 ,  1.40572111,  1.57256466,  1.70997595])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `complex` datatype, and then extract the real component:

```py
import numpy
x = numpy.linspace(-5, 5, 10, dtype=numpy.complex)
roots = x ** 1/3
reals = roots.real
print(reals)
```

```
array([-1.66666667+0.j, -1.2962963 +0.j, -0.92592593+0.j, -0.55555556+0.j,
       -0.18518519+0.j,  0.18518519+0.j,  0.55555556+0.j,  0.92592593+0.j,
        1.2962963 +0.j,  1.66666667+0.j])
```