# Removing complex numbers in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have done a math operation that prints a complex number on the screen. So how do I print to the screen that is not a complex number but real number?

```
import math
k = int(input('input a number: '))
ex1 = pow(k-math.sqrt(pow(k,2)+1),1/3)
print(ex1)
```

This is the printout I got:

```
input a number: 2
(0.30901699437494756+0.535233134659635j)
```

Comment: There are actually a couple of outputs you might want here: the real part of your complex number is just `ex1.real`, and the norm of it is `abs(ex1)`. Both of these results return a real value.

Comment: You can also use `isinstance(ex1, complex)` to check if it's a complex number and do some logic.

Comment: yes i succeeded but then negative number will become positive

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: my desired output is a real number @dibery

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the real cube root of a negative number in Python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30923838/how-to-get-the-real-cube-root-of-a-negative-number-in-python3)

Comment: So in your example, you got `(0.30901699437494756+0.535233134659635j)`. Then what's the expected value of this? 0.30901699437494756?